# Scrapy Impossible to get that field

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape 4 fields: image, link, name, price.

This code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

#scrapy crawl jobs7 -o job7.csv -t csv
    class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "jobs8"
        allowed_domains = ["vapedonia.com"]
        start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/11-mods-potencia-"]

        def parse(self, response):
            products = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container clearfix"]')

            for product in products:
                image = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/img/@src').extract_first()
                link = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/@href').extract_first()
                name = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/p/a/text()').extract_first()
                price = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price"]').extract_first()
                print image, link, name, price
```

gets an error.

I've been trying creating my xpath expression, using the inspecting tool and a plugin. I've tried by myself too. It works in the webpage but not in the script.

I've been fighting for a while now and I can't figure out what's happening.

Does somebody have any idea of what can be happening?

Thanks!

PS: here's the error I get: 
2017-09-21 07:55:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-21 07:55:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-21 07:55:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-09-21 07:55:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.vapedonia.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-09-21 07:55:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.vapedonia.com/11-mods-potencia-> (referer: None)
https://www.vapedonia.com/4688-home_default/-ipv-6x-azul-pionner4you.jpg https://www.vapedonia.com/pionner4you/2075--ipv-6x-azul-pionner4you.html  IPV 6X AZUL - PIONNER4YOU 2017-09-21 07:55:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing https://www.vapedonia.com/11-mods-potencia-> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist\craigslist\spiders\jobs8.py", line 18, in parse
    print image, link, name, price
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 26: character maps to 
2017-09-21 07:55:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-21 07:55:32 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: The only error I get now relates to wrong indentation of source code. If corrected, it works for me.

Comment: The code is working perfectly, please post complete exception details

Comment: So it doesn't work for me. I've just put in the initial message the error.

Answer (score 0):

it was a charset issue, I've put this: price = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price"]').extract_first()**.encode("utf-8")**.

It's a correct solution to me but may be it could be set up at a file level.

Comment: just one thing: just before the class, I wrote: #scrapy crawl jobs7 -o job7.csv -t csv but that is not what I used to crawl the spider, I use #scrapy crawl jobs8 -o job8.csv -t csv. What I usually are tons of tests and I'm used to create new file copying an existing file which normally the last file created. It was just to let it clear that the error was not from this.